# Using a CN1 Eclipse project from another one?

Tags: java, codenameone

In Eclipse, I created one CN1 project and one normal Java project, which depends on the former. The latter contains some utilities (e.g., source code generation) and some JUnit tests. I use the following simple hack:

```
    CodenameOneImplementation impl = new JavaSEPort();
    Util.setImplementation(impl);
    Display.init(impl);
```

It works, but there's a fullscreen window shown and the program doesn't terminate when `main` is done. I know, that it's the normal behavior for GUI applications, but I don't need any GUI as I only initialized `Display`, in order for `Display#getResource` to work.

- How can I get rid of the window (or at least make it small)?
- How can I terminate the program without having to call `System.exit` (i.e., something like running the event handling thread as daemon)?
- Is there more to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
JavaSEPort.setDefaultInitTarget(new JPanel());
```

This would draw the UI of the display into the blank `JPanel`.

About exiting the app you would need to use `System.exit(0)` as the EDT loop and native GUI loop are running. You can stop the EDT but that might not work well for the desktop port so just using exit is easy and common practice.

Comment: This didn't work, but brought me to the relevant code and with `Display.init(new JPanel())`, the windows is gone. `System.exit` is something, I can live with.